# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException can anyone?

Tags: java

This is my homework assignment, I do not really know about Code, so, anyone can help me?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String string = scan.nextLine();
        int index = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(string.charAt(index));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is expected to happen if the index you provide is greater or equal to the length of the string. Compare [this test](https://ideone.com/PoYJLq) with [this one](https://ideone.com/4N1QGY)

Comment: If you think one of the answeres were helpful, mark it as accepted the button below down-upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Typo

Write instead of **this**

```
    int index = scan.nerxtInt();
```

**that**

```
    int index = scan.nextInt();
```

I would recommend debugging with `System.out.println()` when you get some of this errors.
Just check what is inside of your variable. Is it the value which you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you must check the index before use it, maybe it isn't valid in the rang of string:

```
if(index>=0 && index< string.length()){
        System.out.println(string.charAt(index));
}else{
        System.out.println("invalid index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For another way of validating the string and given integer length, you can update your code as:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String string = "";
    try {
        string = scan.nextLine();
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.printf("%d index is out of bound for given string %s%n",string.length(),string);
    }
```